spring boot 2.7.18: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'
I am trying to migrate sprintboot from 2.0.4 to 2.7.18. I have also updated java version to 21 from 8.
io.springfox dependencies are at 2.8.0
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
</dependency>


<dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

When I launch application(mvn clean install), it throws error:

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to
start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
"org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.PatternsRequestCondition.toString()"
because the return value of
"springfox.documentation.spi.service.contexts.Orderings.patternsCondition(springfox.documentation.RequestHandler)"
is null

Seems springfox version is not compatible, but I am not sure.
I couldnt find any documentation for springboot-springfox versions compatibility.
Any input here?

You need add specific configuration to your application.yml file like below
spring: 
  mvc:
    pathmatch:
      matching-strategy: ant_path_matcher

